# Polkadot-JS not calling my contract properly

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, smart-contract, extrinsic, error

I used `PolkadotJS` to call a contract, when i did, it logged the status `"in block"`, Turns out it never makes any state change. I used `contracts-ui` it worked,  but with JS? Never. What can be the reason:
This is my JS snippet:

```
 const value = 10000;
    const gasLimit = 3000n * 1000000n;
    const storageDepositLimit = null;

 // Send the transaction, like elsewhere this is a normal extrinsic
    await contract.tx
        .commence({ storageDepositLimit, gasLimit }, hash, names, parties, ipfs_str, getFutureUnixTime(hours))
        .signAndSend(alice, result => {
            if (result.status.isInBlock) {
                console.log('in a block');
            } else if (result.status.isFinalized) {
                console.log('finalized');
            }
        }).then(() => res.status(200).send({ data: `#elect-0-rate-${hash}` }));
```

Am i not calling it right? I took it off the `PolkadotJS` website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to first dry-run to check for errors and then process the tx:

```
// Get the initial gas WeightV2 using api.consts.system.blockWeights['maxBlock']
const gasLimit = api.registry.createType(
  'WeightV2',
  api.consts.system.blockWeights['maxBlock']
)

// Query the contract message
// This will return the gas required and storageDeposit to execute the message
// and the result of the message
const { gasRequired, storageDeposit, result } = await contract.query.enter(
  account.address,
  {
    gasLimit: gasLimit,
    storageDepositLimit: null,
    value: new BN('1000000000000000000')
  }
)

// Check for errors
if (result.isErr) {
  let error = ''
  if (result.asErr.isModule) {
    const dispatchError = api.registry.findMetaError(result.asErr.asModule)
    error = dispatchError.docs.length ? dispatchError.docs.concat().toString() : dispatchError.name
  } else {
    error = result.asErr.toString()
  }

  console.error(error)
  return
}

// Even if the result is Ok, it could be a revert in the contract execution
if (result.isOk) {
  const flags = result.asOk.flags.toHuman()
  // Check if the result is a revert via flags
  if (flags.includes('Revert')) {
    const type = contract.abi.messages[5].returnType // here 5 is the index of the message in the ABI
    const typeName = type?.lookupName || type?.type || ''
    const error = contract.abi.registry.createTypeUnsafe(typeName, [result.asOk.data]).toHuman()

    console.error(error ? (error as any).Err : 'Revert')
    return
  }
}

// Gas require is more than gas returned in the query
// To be safe, we double the gasLimit.
// Note, doubling gasLimit will not cause spending more gas for the Tx
const estimatedGas = api.registry.createType(
  'WeightV2',
  {
    refTime: gasRequired.refTime.toBn().mul(BN_TWO),
    proofSize: gasRequired.proofSize.toBn().mul(BN_TWO),
  }
) as WeightV2

setLoading(true)

const unsub = await contract.tx
  .enter({
    gasLimit: estimatedGas,
    storageDepositLimit: null,
    value: new BN('1000000000000000000') // 1 TOKEN or it could be value you want to send to the contract in title
  })
  .signAndSend(account.address, (res) => {
    // Send the transaction, like elsewhere this is a normal extrinsic
    // with the same rules as applied in the API (As with the read example,
    // additional params, if required can follow)
    if (res.status.isInBlock) {
      console.log('in a block')
    }
    if (res.status.isFinalized) {
      console.log('Successfully sent the txn')
      unsub()
    }
  })
```

Code snippet from [Astar doc](https://docs.astar.network/docs/build/wasm/interact/astarjs/#send-contract-transaction-the-hard-way)

Comment: The `setLoading()` function is not defined

Comment: I am getting this error -> `Contract trapped during execution.`. But when i use the UI it doesn't give any errors, it just works.